# Elvis Operator (?) on [ngModel] with Dynamic Parameter Name not Working

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a data object `obj` with multiple parameters:

```
export interface obj {
  param1: number;
  param2: number;
  param3: number;
}
```

I would like to dynamically add `mat-grid-tiles` with `mat-form-fields` displaying their value.

I do this by creating an array of the parameter names:

```
params = ['param1', 'param2', 'param3']
```

Then, in my HTML code, I use my `mat-grid-tiles` with `*ngFor` on the parameter names and then assign the reference to my `obj` in `[ngModel]`:

```
<mat-grid-tile [colspan]=1 *ngFor="let param of params">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [ngModel]="coilData[params]" readonly>
  </mat-form-field>
</mat-grid-tile>
```

It works! **However**, because my `obj` is initially null until an API call is made, it seems to throw hundreds of null errors like so:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'param1' of null
```

I realized that I can just use the Elvis Operator: `?`, however I can not seem to figure out how to use this on `[ngModel]` when I am dynamically assigning parameter names to it like this: `[ngModel]="obj[param]"` instead of the usual `[ngModel]="obj?.param1`.

Is it possible to use the Elvis Operator when dynamically applying parameter names to ngModel?

Comment: Try `obj?.[param]`. [MDN's documentation for optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (the name for the Elvis operator) shows that as the syntax.

Comment: Unfortunately, that threw a template parse error as it does not expect the brackets.

Comment: Well, that's the appropriate syntax for the operator. If Angular or TypeScript or whatever can't handle it, then I guess you go the old fashioned way of `obj && obj[param]` or `obj ? obj[param] : null`.

Comment: I was not aware that it was possible to use the ternary operator in this case, thank you.

Comment: Define your obj as `coilData:any={}` -an empty object- NOT only `coilData:any` -an undefined object-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up taking Heretic Monkey's suggestion and used `obj ? obj[param] : null` instead which ended up working for me.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
< ng-container *ngIf="coilData" >
<mat-grid-tile [colspan]=1 *ngFor="let param of params">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [ngModel]="coilData[params]" readonly>
  </mat-form-field>
</mat-grid-tile>
< ng-container />
```